# In the iOS app, why can't I see my suggested edit while it's waiting for review?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, ios-app

After submitting a suggested edit, I receive this message:

> **Thanks for your edit!**
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

In any of my regular browsers, the edited version is, indeed, what I see. In the IOS app (version 1.4.0.249) I receive the same message, but the only thing visible to me is the original text.

Comment: Yep, that is a bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see suggested edits in the app as of 1.3.1.212, it's just not very prominent or that similar to the web.

When you post a suggested edit to a post, the "Edit" button changes to "Edit (1)" (like it does on the web) and tapping the button brings up a diff of your suggested edit.

I've not gone the full distance of showing the suggested edit inline because the API currently exposes questions and suggested edits as two separate calls, so there is a substantial gap between when the app renders the post and when it knows it has a suggested edit it should render instead.

[image: Screenshot showing the Edit (1) button]

Comment: Now that you've explained it, I'm able to do what I want, which is to view the suggested edit. It's just one little extra step, which is fine with me, so, thanks!